# Firebase local emulators not working due to 'webhook_secret' error - How to fix it?

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, firebase-tools

Why I can't start firebase local emulators?

I'm trying to run a functions emulator but I get this error: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function
source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'webhook_secret')
This is key for Stripe, it is in the file .runtimeconfig.json at the root of the project but it somehow does not see the emulator. Even if I remove webhook_secret from there the error will be identical.
The command firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json did not help.
Tried to remove the function that uses this key from the project, but the problem persists.
Everything works for a colleague, so there is no problem in the code.
In logs is written the following:
[debug] [2023-05-14T15:56:44.558Z] Got response from /**/functions.yaml Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'webhook_secret')
[debug] [2023-05-14T15:56:44.563Z] Failed to parse functions.yaml incomplete explicit mapping pair; a key node is missed; or followed by a non-tabulated empty line at line 1, column 60:
... from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of unde ...
^ {"name": "YAMLException", "reason": "incomplete explicit mapping pair; a key node is missed; or followed by a non-tabulated empty line", "mark":{"name":null, "buffer": "Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'webhook_secret')\n\u0000", "position":59, "line":0, "column":59}, "message": "incomplete explicit mapping pair; a key node is missed; or followed by a non-tabulated empty line at line 1, column 60:\n . .. from function source: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of unde . \n ^"}
[debug] [2023-05-14T15:56:44.569Z] shutdown requested via /**/quitquit

Comment: How are you managing your secrets in your manifest?
Try follow this official integration:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/tree/next/firestore-stripe-payments
and this webhook 
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts#L676

Comment: Please include relevant code snippets that allow anyone to reproduce the problem.